# Getting error in predicting feature values from ARIMA when using a dataframe

Tags: r

I am trainig a an ARIMA model

```
> data=read.csv("R1.csv")
> resp=data$RESP
> respNA=resp[1:100]
> model=arima(respNA,order = c(0,0,1),include.mean = FALSE)
> p=predict(model$model,na.ahead=10)
```

but for the last line I get below error:

```
Error in ets(object, lambda = lambda, biasadj = biasadj, allow.multiplicative.trend = allow.multiplicative.trend,  : 
  y should be a univariate time series
```

what is wrong with above code?

I gues the data is coorect when I call print(respNA) , the output is like below:

```
  [1] 0.00000000 0.18333333 0.93333333 0.00000000 0.25000000 0.86666667 0.00000000 0.31666667 0.80000000 0.00000000
 [11] 0.38333333 0.73333333 0.00000000 0.45000000 0.66666667 0.00000000 0.51666667 0.60000000 0.00000000 0.58333333
 [21] 0.53333333 0.00000000 0.65000000 0.46666667 0.00000000 0.71666667 0.40000000 0.00000000 0.78333333 0.33333333
 [31] 0.00000000 0.85000000 0.26666667 0.00000000 0.91666667 0.20000000 0.00000000 0.98333333 0.13333333 0.05000000
 [41] 1.00000000 0.06666667 0.11666667 1.00000000 0.00000000 0.18333333 0.93333333 0.00000000 0.25000000 0.86666667
 [51] 0.00000000 0.31666667 0.80000000 0.00000000 0.38333333 0.73333333 0.00000000 0.45000000 0.66666667 0.00000000
 [61] 0.51666667 0.60000000 0.00000000 0.58333333 0.53333333 0.00000000 0.65000000 0.46666667 0.00000000 0.71666667
 [71] 0.40000000 0.00000000 0.78333333 0.33333333 0.00000000 0.85000000 0.26666667 0.00000000 0.91666667 0.20000000
 [81] 0.00000000 0.98333333 0.13333333 0.05000000 1.00000000 0.06666667 0.11666667 1.00000000 0.00000000 0.18333333
 [91] 0.93333333 0.00000000 0.25000000 0.86666667 0.00000000 0.31666667 0.80000000 0.00000000 0.38333333 0.73333333
```

Comment: Please provide an (minimal) example of your input. It looks like your input data is not correct.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax with `predict` is `predict(your_model, ...)`, i.e. in your case

```
# Fit ARIMA model
model <- arima(respNA,order = c(0,0,1),include.mean = FALSE);

# Predict next 10 steps
p <- predict(model, n.ahead = 10);
p;
$pred
Time Series:
Start = 101
End = 110
Frequency = 1
 [1] 0.2006601 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 [8] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000

$se
Time Series:
Start = 101
End = 110
Frequency = 1
 [1] 0.4155428 0.5847784 0.5847784 0.5847784 0.5847784 0.5847784 0.5847784
 [8] 0.5847784 0.5847784 0.5847784
```

---

### Sample data

```
respNA <- c(0.00000000, 0.18333333, 0.93333333, 0.00000000, 0.25000000, 0.86666667, 0.00000000, 0.31666667, 0.80000000, 0.00000000,
0.38333333, 0.73333333, 0.00000000, 0.45000000, 0.66666667, 0.00000000, 0.51666667, 0.60000000, 0.00000000, 0.58333333,
0.53333333, 0.00000000, 0.65000000, 0.46666667, 0.00000000, 0.71666667, 0.40000000, 0.00000000, 0.78333333, 0.33333333,
0.00000000, 0.85000000, 0.26666667, 0.00000000, 0.91666667, 0.20000000, 0.00000000, 0.98333333, 0.13333333, 0.05000000,
1.00000000, 0.06666667, 0.11666667, 1.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.18333333, 0.93333333, 0.00000000, 0.25000000, 0.86666667,
0.00000000, 0.31666667, 0.80000000, 0.00000000, 0.38333333, 0.73333333, 0.00000000, 0.45000000, 0.66666667, 0.00000000,
0.51666667, 0.60000000, 0.00000000, 0.58333333, 0.53333333, 0.00000000, 0.65000000, 0.46666667, 0.00000000, 0.71666667,
0.40000000, 0.00000000, 0.78333333, 0.33333333, 0.00000000, 0.85000000, 0.26666667, 0.00000000, 0.91666667, 0.20000000,
0.00000000, 0.98333333, 0.13333333, 0.05000000, 1.00000000, 0.06666667, 0.11666667, 1.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.18333333,
0.93333333, 0.00000000, 0.25000000, 0.86666667, 0.00000000, 0.31666667, 0.80000000, 0.00000000, 0.38333333, 0.73333333)
```

Comment: I need to predict 10 ahead samples not just one sample ahead. Can you also explain what is the differnce between model and model$model?

Comment: @Alice (1) What do you mean what's the difference between `model` and `model$model`? For usage in `predict`, one is correct, the other one is not. All functions of the `predict` family take the model return object as first argument, see `predict.glm`, `predict.lm`, `predict.arima` and so on.  According to `?arima` `model$model` contains a "list representing the Kalman Filter used in the fitting". `model`  contains a whole lot more (e.g. estimated parameters, the data, residuals etc.).

Comment: [continued] (2) *"I need to predict 10 ahead samples not just one sample ahead."* This kind of information should've been made clear in the original post. All I took from your question was the incorrect use of the model in `predict`. To predict 10 ahead samples, the correct syntax is `p <- predict(model, n.ahead = 10);`. Note the argument `n.ahead` (not `na.ahead`). I've made a change to my post.